# Dialog box disappears during orientation change in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, customdialog

So I am not a very experience Android programmer, so please be gentle with me :)

I am trying to create an app that uses fragements and from within one of these fragments I am calling a custom dialog box.

```
//create dialog
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.fragment_update_dialog);

//set up data in dialog here

Button bUpdate = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bDialogUpdate);
bUpdate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
//define onclick listener code here
});
dialog.show();
```

This code works fine and I have no issues with it.  But when there is a screen orientation change then my dialog box disappears.

Now I have read several posts on this forum, and other places, so I understand why this is occuring, but I don't find a solution to stop it.

I have tried the 'trick' with the manifest file, but it doesn't work.  (Perhaps because it is in the fragment and not the activity?)

My manifest file includes;

```
<activity
        android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
....
```

and in my main activity I have

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

But this doesn't work.

I also see many comments say that this is not recommened, but can't see how to solve this issue.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Check my answer in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580768/alertdialog-is-disappears-while-reload-the-activity-in-android/16581426#16581426).

Comment: Sorry but thats for an alertdialog, not a custom dialog.

Comment: Oh my, you could just replace it with any dialog you like.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Up to API 13 there was a new value to the configChanges attribute, screenSize

So if you're using large screens make sure to add screenSize in your configChanges attribute:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

**i.e.**

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyMainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" 
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12014384/1218762)

Comment: Thats solved the disappearing dialog (brilliant thanks), but has created another issue!  Now, the dialog box stays, I can perform my update.  But when it returns to the fragment then my fragment view has disappeared, and all of my content (textboxs, spinners etc) have gone.  So what have I done wrong now?

Answer (score 13):

Try to use [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) instead. It restarts after orientation change. You need to extend this class as shown on documentation, and use it to show dialog.

Comment: I looked at doing this, but had other issues.  That being that I couldn't call the DialogFragment from inside another fragement.  All the examples I found on the net where calling from within the activity, and I couldn't even get the code to compile.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith There is example how I show DialogFragment from another fragment: `CustomDialogFragment dialog = new CustomDialogFragment();  dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "tag");` You can find how to create custom DialogFragment in official documentation on link what i provided above.

Comment: DialogFragment is the way to go. No need to make unrecommended changes to the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

By accident i found a way to make your Dialog persist when device orientation changes.

This is C# xamarin code but i believe it can be very easily adapted to java as well.

```
    private void MakeDialogPersist(Dialog dialog)
    {
        WindowManagerLayoutParams wmlp = new WindowManagerLayoutParams();
        wmlp.CopyFrom(dialog.Window.Attributes);
        dialog.Window.Attributes = wmlp;
    }
```

I run this method after i perform dialog.Show();