# Disable Screen rotation in my activity while dialog is showing

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment, android-popupwindow

I have a dialog fragment that shows while my application is doing a task.

I cancel the task that is being executed on the activities `onDestroy()` method is called.

If the user rotates while the popup is showing, android destroys the activity and then redraws it. So I have told it to cancel the task in the `onDestroy()` method. It then stops executing the task and the popup stays there. As it is normally only removed when the task has completed.

I know this is probably not the best way to go about doing it, but I feel it will be a quick fix to my issue and it wont cause any other issues (that I know of).

I want to disable rotation for my application just before the popup is shown, and then I want to re-enable it when the dialog is dimsised.

How would I do this programtically?

like so:
`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);` ?

And where would I do it?  In the `onCreate()` of the dialog? or before I call the dialog from the activity?

Comment: What about trying this instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605952/dialog-box-disappears-during-orientation-change-in-fragment

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this, and tell your experience!
Just when you call your implementation of onDestroy() use

```
onDestroy(){
    OrientationListener foo = new OrientationListener(this.getContext());
    foo.disable();
}
```

I think that if this doesnt work is close to. Anyway you should take a look at
[this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationListener.html).

I hope this will help you!

Comment: The type OrientationListener is deprecated, will this not cause me any issues down the line?

Comment: Oops, my fault, use [OrientationEventListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationListener.html) instead. And I'm not sure this works the way you want. I should have to try it... Anyway someone posted something interesting above

Answer (score 0):

try to implement onDismiss and onShow listeners for your dialog and handle orientation. for example do something like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
    implements DialogInterface.OnDismissListener,DialogInterface.OnShowListener{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new 
        AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Alert message to be shown");
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setOnShowListener(this);
        alertDialog.setOnDismissListener(this);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
        final int screenOrientation = ((WindowManager)  getbaseContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation();
        switch (screenOrientation){
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            break;
    }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps some one.